# I've seen this email protection on a website and would like to know how they have achieved this

Tags: javascript, email, spam-prevention

I would like to know how I can replicate this sort of email protection and what parts of it actually does what please.

```
 <a href="cdn-cgi/l/email-protection.html#d7a7a5bea1b6b4ae97b0b6a3bfb2a5b4b8b9a3b2b9a3f9b4b8ba"><span class="__cf_email__" data-cfemail="0474766d7265677d446365706c6176676b6a70616a702a676b69">[email&#160;protected]</span><script data-cfhash='f9e31' type="text/javascript">/* <![CDATA[ */!function(t,e,r,n,c,a,p){try{t=document.currentScript||function(){for(t=document.getElementsByTagName('script'),e=t.length;e--;)if(t[e].getAttribute('data-cfhash'))return t[e]}();if(t&&(c=t.previousSibling)){p=t.parentNode;if(a=c.getAttribute('data-cfemail')){for(e='',r='0x'+a.substr(0,2)|0,n=2;a.length-n;n+=2)e+='%'+('0'+('0x'+a.substr(n,2)^r).toString(16)).slice(-2);p.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(decodeURIComponent(e)),c)}p.removeChild(t)}}catch(u){}}()/* ]]> */</script></a>
```

Comment: Its just a simple xor code. I made a thing to decode them here https://gist.github.com/neopunisher/e8f561068e696f58f05397ad924b95cc

Answer (score 23):

This is [CloudFlare's](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170016-What-is-Email-Address-Obfuscation-) dynamic email obfuscation. CloudFlare automatically apply the obfuscation to websites that they protect.

If your website is protected by CloudFlare, you can turn the feature on by signing in to the dashboard then Cloudflare.com > ScrapeShield > Email Obfuscation.